# Load Data in Modx FormPanel

Tags: extjs, modx, modx-revolution

I'm working on a Customer Manager Page that basically displays the details of a person object(first name, last name...) using display fields without any editing, my view widget is as follows:

```
Players.panel.View = function(config) {
config = config || {};
Ext.apply(config,{
    border: false
    ,baseCls: 'modx-formpanel'
    ,url: Players.config.connectorUrl
    ,baseParams: { action: 'mgr/player/get' }
    ,items: [{
        html: '<h2>'+_('players.view.title')+'</h2>'
        ,border: false
        ,cls: 'modx-page-header'
    },{
        xtype: 'modx-tabs'
        ,bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px'
        ,defaults: { border: false ,autoHeight: true }
        ,border: true
        ,items: [{
            title: _('players.view.tab-header')
            ,defaults: { autoHeight: true }
            ,items: [{
                html: '<p>'+_('players.view.panel-desc')+'</p><br />'
                ,border: false
            } ,{
                xtype: 'compositefield',
                labelWidth: 120,
                items: [{
                            xtype     : 'displayfield',
                            value: 'First Name:',
                            width     : 120
                        },
                        {
                            xtype     : 'displayfield',
                            value: 'Yehia A.Salam'
                        }
                ]
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
Players.panel.View.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);
};
Ext.extend(Players.panel.View,MODx.Panel);
Ext.reg('players-panel-view',Players.panel.View);
```

However, the 'mgr/player/get' never gets called, i'm sure the connector is working fine since am already using it in another grid widget, am i missing something here, how do i initiate and the ajax call and populate the displayFields.

Appreciate the Help,
And WOW, never thought the learning curve would be so steep for Modx Revolution.

--
Regards.
Yehia A.Salam

Comment: This actually has little to nothing to do with ModX, seeing as you are having extjs problems, which has absolutely nothing to do with ModX.

Comment: it's the modx-formpanel, so there might be something there modx specific

Comment: A lot of things are included with modx, but it still makes them their own, which is why I suggested you look at extjs to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the 'fields' parameter that contains all data fields you want to retrieve via the connector.

Something like that:

```
Players.panel.View = function(config) {
config = config || {};
Ext.apply(config,{
    border: false
    ,baseCls: 'modx-formpanel'
    ,url: Players.config.connectorUrl
    ,baseParams: { action: 'mgr/player/get' }
    ,fields: [
          'id'
          ,'first_name'
          ,'last_name'
          ,...]
    ,...
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create another custom xtype which will call that connector.

```
Players.panel.View = function(config) {
config = config || {};
Ext.apply(config,{
    border: false
    ,baseCls: 'modx-formpanel'
    ,items: [{
        html: '<h2>'+_('players.view.title')+'</h2>'
        ,border: false
        ,cls: 'modx-page-header'
    },{
        xtype: 'modx-tabs'
        ,bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px'
        ,defaults: { border: false ,autoHeight: true }
        ,border: true
        ,items: [{
            title: _('players.view.tab-header')
            ,defaults: { autoHeight: true }
            ,items: [{
                html: '<p>'+_('players.view.panel-desc')+'</p><br />'
                ,border: false
            } ,{
                // this thing is the one that has the url + baseParams
                // and renders the compositefields
                xtype: 'another-xtype-to-call-connector' 
                ,preventRender: true
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
Players.panel.View.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);
};
Ext.extend(Players.panel.View,MODx.Panel);
Ext.reg('players-panel-view',Players.panel.View);
```

In here, `MODx.Panel` is only to generate the layout.